# Render text into LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9

Tags: text, render, directx-9, render-to-texture

How can one render some text on a texture and then display it?

[DirectX 10 Draw Text to texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202010/directx-10-draw-text-to-texture)

This basically doesn't work for me. (it simply does not draw the text.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to draw text in DirectX9 or DirectX10 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with DirectX10, you could use Direct Write. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff485855(v=vs.85).aspx